# Android app is not showing in market for devices which dont have simcard

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

Here are the Manifest Details which my application included

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

Please let me know what makes invisible my app in market for devices which dont have sim card.

Comment: There is a difference between uses feature and uses permission. Please read the docs carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these features also:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Still not showing app in Play store even with above user-feature configuration in manifest